# The plugin generated 80 characters of unexpected output!

Tags: plugin-development, headers

I'm getting this message each time I activate my plugin:

*The plugin generated 80 characters of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugin.*

The only way I can suppress the message is to wrap my activation function code in a conditional (**see below).

How should I rewrite this to prevent the alert?

```
function myPlugin($post)
{
    echo "Whatever is here throws an unexpected output alert when the plugin isa activated";
//I can place code here without issue, but anything that is output via echo throws the alert.
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'myPlugin');
```

Wrapping the function code in the conditional suppresses the alerts:

```
function myPlugin($post)
{
    global $pagenow;
    if ( is_admin() && $pagenow !== 'plugins.php' ) {
        echo "No more alerts when its wrapped this way";
        }
}
 ?>
```

Comment: Isn't the problem that you are outputting data in your activation hook? I don't think you're supposed to do that, since that hook will only fire once in the background, so no output will ever be seen by the user (and indeed, any output is an indication to WordPress that your plugin contains an error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get this kind of message is **usually means your plugin had a syntax error** and was generating that kind of error messages because of how the loading on activation is handled, i.e. HTTP headers are sent after the error message is display.  Your plugin's error message is loaded in an `<iframe>`; have you done a *"View Source"* on the `<iframe>` to see if there's an obvious error message?

Also, you should consider getting an HTTP debugger which can help with this kind of things:

- Windows has the *excellent* and **free** [**Fiddler**](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).
- For Mac OS X there's [**HTTPScoop**](http://www.tuffcode.com/) *(not great, but inexpensive at **US$15**.)*
- There's also [**Charles**](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) for Windows/Mac/Linux *(**US$50** - I may break down and buy it one day. Wish I could get Fiddler on Mac, but since Fiddler comes from Microsoft I don't hold my breath.)*

#### UPDATE

Based on the comments below, here's a screen of me using *"Inspect Element"* in Safari (but you can do the same with Chrome and FireFox, or similar with IE and the Web Developer Toolbar):

[image: Screenshot of Element Inspector on Safari with the WordPress plugin error IFRAME]
<sub>(source: [mikeschinkel.com](https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/skitched-20101101-203609.png))</sub>

You can grab that `<iframe>`d URL and load it directly in your browser to make the process of debugging easier. Something in your plugin is sending q `header()` ***after*** an error message is thrown, that's what that error message means.

[image: Loading WordPress Plugin Activation URL directly from the browser]
<sub>(source: [mikeschinkel.com](https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/skitched-514-20101101-203737.png))</sub>

BTW, I just added a stray character and hence syntax error in my plugin to get it to throw an error which is why you see the error as you do.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I'm missing the iframe element. In firefox, when I right click on the error message, there is not "View Frame Source" available. I only see "View Source".

Comment: The error is only occuring on activation, but no iframe is present that I can tell.

Comment: Perhaps I can wrap the code in the activation function in an is_editing() wrapper? Not sure if such exists, but my plugin code only needs to be executed when editing a post or page.

Comment: I've downloaded fiddler and checked its values after activating the plugin. I can't see any errors raised there, only in WP.

Comment: @Scott B - When you say "I can't see any errors raised there, on in WP" where is "there?" Did you drill down and look at the responses that were being sent?

Comment: By "there" I mean in fiddler, I'm clicking on each row that pops up there to see the details in the right panel.

Comment: @Scott B - See UPDATE above.

Comment: @Mike, AHA! I figured out the problem with no iframe. It does not create an iframe because there is no error. This is just a warning message raised by WP. To verify, I created an obvious error condition and I DO see the iframe in that case.

Comment: @Scott B - So did you figure out the original problem?

Comment: @MikeSchinkel The problem only occurs inside functions that are hooked to de-/activation/uninstall hooks. You're simply not _allowed_ to echo something there. This will _close to always_ result in exactly the reported error.

Comment: @Zack I added it as answer below. Upvotes are appreciated :)

Comment: @kaiser I already upvoted yours :)

Comment: What if it is not my plugin, can't fix it and there is no `iframe` for me? Just trying to catch some error log to send to plugin author.

Answer (score 5):

## USE DEBUG:

*(creates log file **error_activation.txt** in your plugin folder)*

```
add_action('activated_plugin','my_save_error');
function my_save_error()
{
    file_put_contents(dirname(__file__).'/error_activation.txt', ob_get_contents());
}
```

Comment: Actually, it creates a log file in the same directory as the file that has this code. It can be your child theme folder if you put it in the functions.php file.

Comment: Probably more optimal to use `error_log(ob_get_clean());`.

Answer (score 2):

Sry, for the late answer, but I just stumbled upon and the answer is really simple:

**Never** echo *anything* inside functions that are used on de-/activation/uninstall hooks. This will **always** result in the above mentioned error message.

Answer (score 1):

I've just been exploring this problem and what I've found is that the problem can be caused by errors in the php (like calling a deprecated function) which Wordpress suprresses, FTP garbling or by having code outside of the 'php' tags.

I don't think that Mike is correct above. The unexpected output issue is handled differently than a fatal error, firstly, wordpress suppresses the issue, it gives the 'unexpected output' message and more importantly it does actually activate the plugin and redirects back to the plugin page whereas with an error it just dies. I don't think that there will be anything useful in the frame and I don't think that the headers will let you the output that wordpress didn't expect which is what will provide the clues for solving the underlying issue.

There are a number of solutions to getting at the unexpected output text which require either hacking the plugins.php file or setting an event handler for the 'activate_plugin' action.

FWIW, you can [find my solutions](http://peter.janetbruten.co.uk/?p=161) <sup>[*mirror*](https://web.archive.org/web/20140928091731/http://peter.janetbruten.co.uk/it/wordpress/wordpress-coding/unexpected-output-when-activating-plugins/)</sup> here (work in progress!) with some links to other people's solutions from which I borrowed shamelessly!

Comment: Completely agree. WP will suppress errors and not activate the plugin. This "error" received by the OP (and myself just now) lets the plugin activate.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue, i tried to remove the code and did everything but still the same problem

the real solution for me was the following.

1. at the end of the file which contains the header of the plugin i removed closing php ?> and the problem will be solved
2. at the end of the plugin file which contains the header of the plugin remove the extra line breaks after the closing php ?>

my plugin file ended at line 69 and there were 7 more spaced after the last php code so in the editor the file was up to 66, my error was "The plugin generated 7 characters of unexpected...." when i removed extra lines up to 69 the was error gone,

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. It occured thad the plugin php file had bad encoding. I simply copied whole content to a new notepad file and saved it with ansi encoding. Error message dissapeard. Of ccourse now there are language issues but it's some other case. Regards