# The plugin generated XXX characters of unexpected output...help?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am working on a plugin that creates a custom post type and then creates a custom template file for the activated theme. The plugin is done editing. But I've received an error while uploading that says "The plugin generated 265 characters of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugin."

Here is the code for the main file: http://pastebin.com/jztzG499

What can I do to solve this problem? I have looked through other sites and Stackexchange but none of them were helpful.

Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The plugin generated 80 characters of unexpected output!](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3533/the-plugin-generated-80-characters-of-unexpected-output)

Comment: Forgive me if this is a stupid question but do you have a <?php at the very start.

Comment: yes. there is a <?php at the start and ?> at the end.

Comment: @MagentaCuda Here is the full code: http://pastebin.com/jztzG499

Comment: @MagentaCuda Here is the single-products.php (template file): http://pastebin.com/F7FjpdwM

Comment: There must be more to this plugin. Where is the plugin header? Where is single-product.php? This error is usually caused by outputting very early in the WordPress processing before WordPress has sent the HTTP headers. The code given does not seem to output anything so I think the error is somewhere else.

Comment: Here is the main file: http://pastebin.com/jztzG499 and here is the single-product.php: http://pastebin.com/F7FjpdwM

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. This line:

`"if (!isset($pd_plugin_instance)) $pd_plugin_instance = new Products();"`

Was causing all the error. I removed the Widget section from the plugin but forgot to remove it. After removing it, the error was gone.